# Ragged alignat environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, alignat

First time posting here, let me know if I can make the question clearer/better. Below is a simple example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
y_{ijk} \sim N(&\theta_{ijk}, se_{ijk}) \\ 
&\downarrow && \\
&\theta_{ijk} = &&\beta_{1ij} t_{ijk}^{p_1}  \\
& &&\downarrow \\
& &&\beta_{1ij}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Hierarchical model]

I'm hoping to move the `\beta_{1ij} t_{ijk}^{p_1}` term to its normal positioning next to the equals sign. This is tantamount to aligning it with the subscripts on `se_{ijk}`. I understand that I could align it with `se`, however this would alter its natural spacing, causing essentially the same problem. Even if it is possible to align with the subscript using `&&`, one would have to spend a great deal of time searching for the exact letter with which to align *each time* one wanted to start a new alignment at a letter that has text above it.

Is there a natural way to accomplish such a thing? Specifically,

1. Is it possible to end old alignments and start new ones within an `alignat` environment? (I suspect the answer here is no.)

or

2. Is it possible to align in a "ragged array" of sorts, so that new alignments don't necessarily have to follow the old ones? That is, is there a way to start new alignments where the text below aligns but the text above does not necessarily have to align?

I've spent a good deal of fooling around with tikz, but I would prefer to align objects vertically, and ultimately it seems to lead back to the same issue presented here. Thanks for any help here!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're best served with old chap `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{rclcl}
y_{ijk} \sim N( & \theta_{ijk} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{, se_{ijk})} \\
&\downarrow \\
&\theta_{ijk} & {}={} & \beta_{1ij} & t_{ijk}^{p_1}  \\
&&&\downarrow \\
&&&\beta_{1ij}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some more work is needed in order to get vertically aligned subscripts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\newcommand{\fs}{^{\vphantom{p_1}}}
\begin{array}{rclcl}
y\fs_{ijk} \sim N( & \theta\fs_{ijk} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{, se\fs_{ijk})} \\
&\downarrow \\
&\theta\fs_{ijk} & {}={} & \beta\fs_{1ij\vphantom{k}} & t_{ijk}^{p_1}  \\
&&&\downarrow \\
&&&\beta\fs_{1ij}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions, with a better alignment of the `\downarrow` thanks to the `eqparbox` package. One solution uses the `alignat*`environment combined with the `\mathlap` command from `mathtools`, the other one uses  an `aligned` environment nest in a simple `align*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
 \newcommand\eqmathbox[2][M]{\eqmakebox[M#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  y_{ijk} ∼ N(&\eqmathbox[1]{\theta_{ijk}}, se_{ijk}) \\
  &\eqmathbox[1]{\downarrow} \\
    & \theta_{ijk} =\! \begin{aligned}[t] & \eqmathbox[2]{\beta_{1ij}} t_{ijk}^{p₁} \\
  &\eqmathbox[2]{\downarrow} \\
  &\beta_{1ij}
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  y_{ijk} ∼ N(&\mathrlap{\eqmathbox[1]{\theta_{ijk}}, se_{ijk})} \\
    & \eqmathbox[1]{\downarrow} & & \\
    & \theta_{ijk} ={} & & \eqmathbox[2]{\beta_{1ij}} t_{ijk}^{p₁} \\
    & & & \eqmathbox[2]{\downarrow} \\
    & & & \beta_{1ij}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]